# Multiple onpopstate event

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

I need to work with History API for an application.
My problem is that some "home" jQuery plugins already implement an event for **popstate**

it is possible to have more than one **popstate** event for an unique view ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", console.log);
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(){console.log("I am also called")});
```

This seems to work fine for me.

Edit: Now with multiple events. For some reason Chrome won't fire twice the console log of the event though

Comment: It work too for me, my question is if is possible to have two event like that for the same page

Comment: Axnyff console.log is a function by itself. I don't see the reason calling it on an anonymous function. Just call "console.log("Message")" again. Works fine for me! And yes OrcusZ, you can use it more than one times.

Comment: Thanks this work. Another problem that they are all fired at the same time and i want to manage them separatly

Answer (score 0):

**I mistakenly used the following in two React components** (Result: The second component overrides the behaviour of the first component, so it didn't trigger):

```
window.onpopstate = function (e) { /* Do something */ }
```

**Instead I used the following:**

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", /* Do something */ )
```